# How to calculate velocity from speed, current location, and destination point

Tags: vectors

I'm creating a game and I need my unit to move at a static speed.
I command the unit to move from his current position `(x0, x1)` to a new position `(x, y)`.

So I know the speed of the unit, and I know both end points of the movement, now I need to calculate the velocity vector at which the unit moves.
How would I do this?

I figured I need (well, to make it easier for me to understand) a triangle where the hypotenuse is the speed, and the end points of the hypotenuse are the movement's coordinates:

[image: Speed]

Now I can calculate the velocity vector using

```
velocity.x = x - x0
velocity.y = y - y0
```

But it's going *way* too fast. How do I know how big the `x` and `y` of my velocity should be?

**Edit:**

And the unit moves one step at a time, so basically

```
unit.x += velocity.x
unit.y += velocity.y
```

Now I need it to move the length equal to its speed on each step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a *constant* speed $s$, initial position $(x_0, y_0)$, and final position $(x,y)$, we can find the velocity vector as follows.  First define $d=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$, the distance travelled.  Then the velocity vector is $$\begin{cases}v_x = \dfrac{s}{d}(x-x_0) \\ v_y = \dfrac{s}{d}(y-y_0)\end{cases}$$

Comment: I still can't get my head completely around this (it'll probably snap), but this worked, so thanks! :D

Comment: $\text{speed} = \dfrac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$.  So for $v_x$ we have that $x-x_0$ is the $x$-distance travelled and $\dfrac ds$ is the time it took.

Comment: Oh! Now I got it--thanks!